# why does this work fine the first time around but not the 2nd time around?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, static, quartz-scheduler

I am using a scheduler that will send out reminders through a library called actionMailer. I however need the httpcontext to work as well actionMailer uses mvc.

So I came up with this:

// global aspx.

```
protected void Application_Start()
{
    // Hook our DI stuff when application starts
    IKernel kernel = SetupDependencyInjection();

    // get the reminder service
    IScheduledRemindersService scheduledRemindersService = kernel.Get<IScheduledRemindersService>();
    RemindersController.iScheduledReminedrService = scheduledRemindersService;
    RemindersController.StartScheduler();
}
```

// Reminder Controller

```
private static HttpContext httpContext;
public static void StartScheduler()
{
    // needed for action mailer
    httpContext = System.Web.HttpContext.Current;
    iScheduledReminedrService.StartAppointmentRemindersSchedule();
}
```

// Scheduler Service

```
public void StartAppointmentRemindersSchedule()
{
    // get a scheduler and start it.
    IScheduler scheduler = GetScheduler();
    scheduler.Start();

    // setup a job
    JobDetail jobDetail = SetupJob("AppointmentRemindersJob", typeof(AppointmentRemindersJob));

    //setup a trigger
    SimpleTrigger trigger = SetupSimpleTrigger("AppointmentRemindersTrigger");

    // schedule the job
    scheduler.ScheduleJob(jobDetail, trigger);
}
```

//Appointment Job

```
public void Execute(JobExecutionContext context)
{
    // code above to get CalendarAppointments
    RemindersController.CalendarAppointmentsReminders(calendarAppointments);
}
```

//Reminder Controller

```
[NonAction]
public static void CalendarAppointmentsReminders(List<CalendarAppointment> appointments)
{
    // set it to have a http context so we can send out emails through mvc mailer.
    System.Web.HttpContext.Current = httpContext;

    List<CalendarAppointmentReminderVM> vm = Mapper.Map<List<CalendarAppointment>, List<CalendarAppointmentReminderVM>>(appointments);

    foreach (var v in vm)
    {
        new EmailController().SendCalendarAppointmentNotifiation(v).DeliverAsync();
    }
}
```

// email controller

```
public EmailResult SendCalendarAppointmentNotifiation(CalendarAppointmentReminderVM vm)
{
    To.Add(vm.To);
    Subject = String.Format("Hi");
    return Email("SendCalendarAppointmentEmail", vm);
}
```

Works perfectly the first time I start up the application and run it. After that it crashes on the 2nd time around

> System.NullReferenceException was
>   unhandled by user code
>   Message=Object reference not set to an
>   instance of an object.
>   Source=WebDev.WebHost40   StackTrace:
>          at Microsoft.VisualStudio.WebHost.Connection.get_RemoteIP()
>          at Microsoft.VisualStudio.WebHost.Connection.get_RemoteIP()
>          at Microsoft.VisualStudio.WebHost.Request.GetRemoteAddress()
>          at System.Web.HttpRequest.get_IsLocal()
>          at System.Web.HttpRequestWrapper.get_IsLocal()
>          at System.Web.WebPages.WebPageBase.ExecutePageHierarchy()
>          at System.Web.Mvc.WebViewPage.ExecutePageHierarchy()
>          at System.Web.WebPages.WebPageBase.ExecutePageHierarchy(WebPageContext
>   pageContext, TextWriter writer,
>   WebPageRenderingBase startPage)
>          at System.Web.Mvc.RazorView.RenderView(ViewContext
>   viewContext, TextWriter writer, Object
>   instance)
>          at System.Web.Mvc.BuildManagerCompiledView.Render(ViewContext
>   viewContext, TextWriter writer)
>          at ActionMailer.Net.EmailResult.RenderViewAsString(ControllerContext
>   context, IView view)
>          at ActionMailer.Net.EmailResult.AddMessageViews(ControllerContext
>   context)
>          at ActionMailer.Net.EmailResult.ExecuteResult(ControllerContext
>   context)
>          at ActionMailer.Net.MailerBase.Email(String
>   viewName, Object model, String
>   masterName)
>          at EmailController.SendCalendarAppointmentNotifiation(CalendarAppointmentReminderVM
>   vm) in EmailController.cs:line 80
>          at RemindersController.CalendarAppointmentsReminders(List`1
>   appointments) in
>   RemindersController.cs:line 61
>          at AppointmentRemindersJob.Execute(JobExecutionContext
>   context) in
>   AppointmentRemindersJob.cs:line 40
>          at Quartz.Core.JobRunShell.Run()
>   InnerException:

Comment: Where's the rest of the error?  Specifically, what error are you getting?

Comment: I just wanted to let you know that I've added a standalone version of ActionMailer that doesn't rely on MVC.  It's a little more limited in what it can do, but feel free to check it out: http://geeksharp.com/2011/07/06/actionmailer-0-6-released/

Comment: Sweet. That looks really cool. When I have time I definitely going to implement this into my site. Keep up the good work! So since the first release of does not support html helpers. I am guessing I just @Model in combination with standard html controls.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The HttpContext is not going to be reliably available out side of an actual http request made into IIS. Even if you set it to a static field. You could maybe try mocking a local request made to the site to kick off the email. I don't know anything about ActionMailer, but perhaps their is a way to use their framework outside of the controller?

To mock a request you'll need to know the URL of the action you are targeting first, something like this should be a setting configured by the developer, or by the site automatically if possible.

```
        var client = new System.Net.WebClient();
        client.DownloadString("http://localhost/Controller/Action");
```

This is not a recommended approach as their may be issues with permissions opening sockets and such. By far the best way to send an email is using framework that already exists such as     System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient

Comment: No there is no really way to use their framework outside of the controller at this current time. How could I do this mocking of a local request?

Comment: The underlying code the farmework uses is probably SmtpClient what the framework is doing is allow you to write nice looking emails by using masterpages and views. The drawback to this is that it needs httpcontext as that is what asp.net mvc needs and unfortunately I am using it in a situation that does not have a live mvc request.